# ACPI error when installing ubuntu 16.04 in HP Pavilion 15-bc513tx

Tags: hp, acpi

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an HP Pavilion 15-bc513tx but it keeps on displaying "ACPI error". I have downloaded and installed the latest BIOS from HP website, but still the problem persists. "ACPI already exist" and many other error messages are coming. Finally stopping the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

HP customer care is pathetic I must say. Also they have a messed up UEFI system which makes things complicated. I have formatted nearly 100 systems and installed Ubuntu/Fedora/Redhat/Linux mint but never faced this issue.

I solved the problem myself after 4 hours of struggle. If anyone struggling for this... I am mentioning the hacks below

Just edit the grub boot file pressing "e" and add the following boot options just after the word "quite splash" ...

pci=nommconf modprobe.blacklist=nouveau

"modprobe.blacklist=nouveau" basically ignore the ACPI errors but don't solve it, solving ACPI errors need to add the option ACPI=off  or  lib.noacpi=1. But this option may lead to inactiveness of input devices mouse/touchpad/keyboard. So just ignore it.

Now press F10 and start booting into Ubuntu...

Once the installation starts and you see some dots are blinking (as if the system is searching for something), just unplug your bootable USB and re-plug it on the same port (in case it is DVD-ROM, just open the tray and close). You are done!!!

The trick can save your few hours and obviously save you from going to a "breaking head" situation.

GOOD LUCK.